# Das gynäkologische Konsil ist für heute Mittag schon angemeldet

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This sentence in the context of conversation between two physicians discussing the condition of a patient.

> Arzt: Wir melden für morgen eine Magenspiegelung an. Das gynäkologische Konsil ist für heute Mittag schon angemeldet.

I understand the meaning of the verb "anmelden". But what does this verb mean in this sentence "Das gynäkologische Konsil ist für heute Mittag schon angemeldet"? does it mean "announced"?

Comment: The critical second sentence has an unusual word order which would need finetuning in writing. Either *ist SCHON für heute Mittag angemeldet* to emphasize the "so early" aspect or *ist schon anmeldet - für heute Mittag* to emphasize, that it has been already taken care of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd probably go for *scheduled*, but there's really no way to tell without more context.

Comment: It is clear now ... thanks ... 
We scheduled her for an investigation .... Wir haben sie die Untersuchung angemeldet.?

Comment: @Millen "Wir haben sie **zu der** Untersuchung angemeldet."

Comment: @Millen As a side note, what's scheduled is probably more of a (medical) examination, not an investigation ;)

Comment: @Henning Kocherbeck I think a medical (gynecological) *assessment* is a better fit here. A medical *assessment* is an *evaluation* which might include not only *a physical* examination but also history-taking, laboratory and imaging. However, I think *consultation* as a literary translation is the best fit.